# How will saving user marked text affect site performance

Tags: php, ajax, performance, drupal, database-performance

We have a website that provides educational content to students.

I am currently implementing a feature on this website, where every time a user marks text from the content, jquery is run to pick the marked text, and call ajax to save it to the database. This is merely for analytics / heatmap purposes.

It has been less than 20 hours since I made this feature live and I already got 16k (and counting) records on my table. Will this have a huge impact on overall site speed and performance?

Do you have suggestions or idea on how should this feature be done more efficiently?

Thanks!

UPDATE with more details:
Database schema: MySQL, 4 fields

- int(10)
- varchar(255)
- text
- date (timestamp)

Code is a very simple jquery ajax - .get() and a simple insert query on my php file

Comment: why are you doing this? do the users know? what is the site, so i can avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by "marks text". Selecting text? Well then it all depends on what type of site you're making. Is it mostly content? You didn't provide any information about your implementation, so how could we say a more "efficient" way?

Comment: Yes, by selecting text. Jquery is run on mouseup.

@Dagon We are doing this for analytics, to know which text users mark the most before pasting it for search. To know which content users like the most and stuff. Is it illegal or something?

Comment: "Is it illegal or something?" in some jurisdictions yes. holding data about peole without there knowledge can be illegal.

Comment: @MikeMurko What details do I need to include? Basically, jquery is run on user's mouseup action, then the marked text is saved to the database thru ajax.

Comment: @MikeMurko yes, the site is all about content / providing information regarding certain topics. a LOT of content / drupal nodes

Comment: @Bibokid more information like perhaps a code sample? your table schema? I mean, are you just simply asking "wow are you guys also suprised I made 16k records as well?". it's not surprising to me. and it also doesn't seem particularly relevant for analytics. How do you know they're not just arbitrarily selecting text (as I often do)? Why don't you look into clickmaps/heatmaps?

Comment: @MikeMurko Thank you for taking the time to help. I updated my post. Yes, that's exactly what my client originally wanted, a "copy heatmap". We have an admin for this feature where copied text are ordered by the number of times they are copied. And are planning to implement a heatmap feature in the future (text are color coded when the content is vied by the admin)

Comment: @MikeMurko Sorry, i am very much newbie with regards to site performance and server admin. Yes, I was surprised by 16k records at a very short amount of time, i am sure you guys get way more than this. BUt this just got me worried and wanted other coder's opinion.

Comment: @Bibokid 16k for a proper database (assuming MySQL here?) is really nothing. also you can generate vast amounts of data by collecting any amount of information - so it's not surprising even on the smallest of sites.

Comment: yes mySQL thanks! what really bothered me is the amount of data we will get in this table, for example, in 30 days. will it still be ok? again thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously logging huge amounts of arbitrary data will affect performance. Your database (which you don't specify) is busy writing records of people clicking randomly on their screen. Your web server is swamped with thousands of requests. So yes, it will affect performance. The only question is how much - and that my friend, has to be found via testing. You could use Selenium to test the user selecting text. You could look at your servers' RAM/CPU/network levels in peak usage times with this feature enabled or disabled. Although all this boils down to - does perceptibly affect your load times or interactions while browsing your site? If no, then just keep logging this (kind of weird) data.

I can't speak to any legality of tracking this. I suspect little to no one will care unless you're Facebook and have privacy watchdogs with their noses up your you-know-what. If you are Facebook, please let us know so we have another reason to deactivate our account.

Comment: hahahaha. No we are not facebook. The website is not very big and simply a site that provides educational content for students.

Thank you for this. I will look on the server settings / config (which i do not have access yet).